# Adding a custom facebook tab to a facebook page

Tags: facebook

I have a page called Wesleys Shop and I want to add a tab to it via the API. I have read the documentation about using the http post on the app_id/tabs but I couldn't get my head around it.
I have worked with the graph allot but this has me stumped.

I was doing research and I got back something like

```
https://graph.facebook.com/277630045596385/tabs?app_id=137964672905791&method=POST&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
```

I got back "(#210) Subject must be a page."

Can anybody help?

THanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you're using the access_token of the page, not the access_token of the logged in user.